# Save and restore canvas rectangle after draw circle on mouse move

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas rectangle shape on pageload. My requirement is, I want to draw a circle on the rectangle on mouse hover and want to remove it after leave the rectangle. Now I can draw a circle on mouse over the rectangle. But i can't remove that circle after leave the rectangle.  I save the state before drawing the circle and restore the state after draw circle. But my code is not working. Anyone please let me, what i did wrong?

```
RectMouseMove: function (evt) {
                this.ctx.save();
                this.ctx.beginPath();
                this.ctx.rect(this.X, this.Y, this.Width, this.Height);
                this.ctx.clip();                   
                this.drawCircle(this.options);
                this.ctx.restore();
   },
   drawCircle: function (options) {
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.arc(options.cx, options.cy, options.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        this.ctx.fillStyle = options.fill;
        this.ctx.globalAlpha = options.opacity;
        this.ctx.fill();
        this.ctx.lineWidth = options["stroke-width"];
        this.ctx.strokeStyle = options.stroke;
        this.ctx.stroke();
    }
```

Thanks,
Bharathi.

Comment: You're saving the state on every single mousemove, see something wrong there?

Comment: Sorry.. i have modified code now..

Answer (score 1):

Calling `restore` will not revert back to how the canvas was when you called `save`. In other words, it does not remove any transformations drawn onto the canvas. What `save` does is push the current settings to the top of the stack so when you call `restore` it'll pop and use those settings.

Example:

```
var c = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = c.getContext('2d');

function draw(e) {
    ctx.fillStyle = '#09F';
    ctx.fillRect(e.x, e.y, 10, 10);
}

function reset() {
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    ctx.save();
}

reset();

c.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
c.addEventListener('mouseleave', reset);
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/rgfdc3uw/**